# How to separate a string to its characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to separate a string to its characters.

e.x: `"hello world!"` to `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", ... , "!"]`

I tried .split() but it just separates words.

what should I do?

Comment: `list("hello world!")` ? magic ...

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
list("hello world!")
```

Output:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could go about this!

**The easiest:**

Like @RomanPerekhrest said, using `list("hello world!")` would create a list of all the elements in the string. This is definitely the ideal answer.

**Doing it the hard way:**

If you want to get *fancy* (which is not better in this case but I wanted to include it for completeness), you could also do a list comprehension. This would look like

```
result = [x for x in "hello world!"]
```

This will take each element in "hello world!" and append it to a list, and return that in the variable `result`.